# Storing an array of Integers to WOM

Tags: code-golf, integer

Very few, if any, programs or applications have utilised the proposed spec for [WOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory) which was initially thought up in the early 1970s as a polar opposite to ROM, so your task is to take a dataset of n Integers and simulate storing it to a WOM schema as a proof of concept.

Your array must contain 1 or more integers. Smallest solution wins.

Comment: Hopefully you have realised the date?

Comment: The story behind the WOM spec is here: http://www.sigwom.com/?page_id=17

Comment: For me very clear what OP is asking. "Have you had your second coffee yet?"

Comment: I don't typically drink coffee so no

Comment: Point is, who is awake and who is still half asleep?

Comment: [Related](http://www.coventrytelegraph.net/news/coventry-news/lady-godiva-gets-covered-up-12824907)

Comment: Anyone for a cup of Green Tea?